# Avoiding circular includes with shared_ptrs

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, circular-dependency

I have a pair of classes for which I can't seem to avoid the circular include problem:

**point.h**

```
#include group.h // Needed for GroupOfPoints::weak_ptr

class Point
{
    private:
        double _x;
        double _y;

        // Groups of points that this point belongs too
        std::vector<GroupOfPoints::weak_ptr> _groups;

    public:
        typedef std::shared_ptr<Point> shared_ptr;
        typedef std::weak_ptr<Point> weak_ptr;

        Point(); // Constructor
        // etc...
}
```

**group.h**

```
#include point.h // Needed for Point::shared_ptr

class GroupOfPoints
{

    private:
        // Collection of points that fall in this group
        std::vector<Point::shared_ptr> _points;

    public:
        typedef std::shared_ptr<GroupOfPoints> shared_ptr;
        typedef std::weak_ptr<GroupOfPoints> weak_ptr;

        GroupOfPoints(); // Constructor
        // etc...

}
```

I understand that shared and weak pointers exist in duality to prevent circular ownership, but how can I utilize that duality without circular includes in the case where the pointers are member variables (i.e. must defined in a header rather than an implementation file)?

Comment: Forward-declare a class (`class Foo;`) instead of including the header in one of the files?

Comment: `class GroupOfPoints; class Point { std::vector<std::weak_ptr<GroupOfPoints>> _groups; };`

Comment: Ah I didn't realize one could do that with classes. I'm was only familiar with forward declarations of functions

Comment: "_I understand that shared and weak pointers exist in duality to prevent circular ownership_" No. Wrong. Circular ownership is prevented with correct design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get rid of this:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Point> shared_ptr;
typedef std::weak_ptr<Point> weak_ptr;
```

I do not see the point.

`std::shared_ptr<Foo>` is clearer than `Foo::shared_ptr`.

Now, forward declare `class Point;` and `class Group;`.  This can be in place of `#include <point.h>`, or *before* including the other header file.

Next ensure your *constructor* are **defined** where they can see the entire declaration of the other class; whereever you call `make_shared<Foo>` or `new Foo` or `delete Foo` or `shared_ptr<Foo>(pFoo)`.  Shared pointers type erase destruction at construction time.

Comment: Thank you. The point of the typedef is because I was previously using boost pointers and got in this habit when I had to switch all my code to the C++11 smart points--who knows: maybe C++20 will have some crazy new shared_ptr type?  And the constructors would be defined in either the cpp file or further down. It just didn't seem necessary to  write them out fully to get my point across

Comment: @marc the typedefs can become aliases *outside* of the type.